# AVG of a calculated field

Tags: sql-server

I want to calculate the AVG member life time. Therefor I need to make a calculation between the column : member_since and Gettime/Currentsystemtime what syntax do I need for this function? I want the outcome of this is Years,  afterwards I can to calculate the AVG of the outcome.

```
SELECT     yelping_since
FROM            [Star model incremental]
WHERE        (date >= '2011-12-31 00:00:00.000') AND (date <= '2013-01-01 00:00:00.000') AND (city = N'Toronto')
```

THis is the view on which the calculation needs to be done
[image: Screenshot of the data]

The calculation needs te be done between Yelping_since and current time to get the total member time

Comment: please also provide some sample data and the expected result

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the data and the expected result is the average memberlifetime in Years. So a single number als an indication what the AVG is of all members is the stated view

Comment: you can use `DATEDIFF()` to find the different between 2 datetime

Comment: When i use select datediff(year, Yelping_since, getdate,) as datediff it says column getdate doesnot exist, what statement do I need for systemtime?

Comment: should be `select datediff(year, Yelping_since, getdate())` Please refer to documentation for more information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/getdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for, hope it helps:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(MemberLifeTime) AS AvgMemberLifeTime
FROM 
(
    SELECT 
        DATEDIFF(year, Yelping_since, GETDATE()) AS MemberLifeTime
    FROM 
        [vYourView]
) test
```